# Flutter align widget in child of ExpansionTile with part in title

Tags: flutter

I am creating a `Card` with an `ExpansionTile` inside. The `ExpansionTile` has multiple widgets in the title and I want to align my children with one of those title items.

Pseudo code of what I would like to achieve:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: ExpansionTile(
            title: Row(
                children: [Text("Item 1 is right here"), Icon(Icons.star)]
            ),
            children: [
                Text("align text in the child here with the image"), // How could we align?
            ],
        ),
    );
}
```

[image: Two Card items with an ExpansionTile]

Comment: it will easier to create with custom widget Row(Clumn) with some animation ig